# Unable to detangle code create by org-babel-tangle

Tags: org-babel

With a single literate program trying to output rust, in a file called `simu.org`:

```
* Simu 

`simu` is a program to simulate counting up to a certain number.

The program has two main parts:

** Gathering input

We simply get the first parameter, panicking if there is nothing specified.

#+name: gather-input
#+begin_src rust :noweb yes :comments noweb
let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
if args.len() < 2 {
    panic!("No argument provided");
}
<<parse-input>>
#+end_src

This uses the `env` package, so we should add it:

#+name: imports
#+begin_src rust :noweb yes :comments noweb
use std::env;
#+end_src

The input is provided as a string, so we need to parse, and report error if it fails.

#+name: parse-input
#+begin_src rust :noweb yes :comments noweb
let count = args[1].parse::<i32>().unwrap();
#+end_src

** Counting up to the number

The loop is pretty straigforward:

#+name: count
#+begin_src rust :noweb yes :comments noweb
let mut i = 0;
while i < count {
    <<print-current-number>>
    i = i+1;
}
#+end_src

Displaying the counter is a matter of presentation:

#+name: print-current-number
#+begin_src rust :noweb yes :comments noweb
println!("Current number is {}", i);
#+end_src

** Tying things up

#+name: main
#+begin_src rust :tangle main.rs :noweb yes :comments noweb
<<imports>>
fn main() {
    <<gather-input>>
    <<count>>
}
#+end_src
```

Using `org-babel-tangle` creates the following file `main.rs` next to `simu.org`:

```
// [[file:simu.org::main][main]]
// [[file:simu.org::imports][imports]]
use std::env;
// imports ends here
fn main() {
    // [[file:simu.org::gather-input][gather-input]]
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    if args.len() < 2 {
        panic!("No argument provided");
    }
    // [[file:simu.org::parse-input][parse-input]]
    let count = args[1].parse::<i32>().unwrap();
    // parse-input ends here
    // gather-input ends here
    // [[file:simu.org::count][count]]
    let mut i = 0;
    while i < count {
        // [[file:simu.org::print-current-number][print-current-number]]
        println!("Current number is {}", i);
        // print-current-number ends here
        i = i+1;
    }
    // count ends here
}
// main ends here
```

The tangled program works. But, if I open a buffer on the generated `main.rs`, and I edit the content of the generic code, my understanding is that using `org-babel-detangle` should edit the source `simu.org` file.

However, I only get the error `Not in tangled code`.

The documentation is a bit confusing: it mentions that the `:comments` block header should be set to `links`. However, using `links` does not generate any comment in the output `main.rs`. Since I'm using `noweb` blocks, I assumed it had to be `noweb`, but it might a mistake.

What should I change ?

Comment: I get the same thing and I think it's a bug. Please report it with `M-x org-submit-bug-report`.